# JavaScript not waiting for promise to resolve. When using Async /Await to scan AWS DynamoDB

Tags: javascript, async-await, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I am using Javascipt AWS-SDK to scan AWS dynamodb. I expect my code to hold execution until it gets the result from the scan. What did I  do wrong .

```
async function scanDb() {
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  params = {
    TableName: 'testdriveenvs',
    FilterExpression : 'EnvStatus = :a',
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {':a' : 'Inuse'}
  };

  var objectPromise = await docClient.scan(params).promise().then((data) => {
    return data.Items 
  });

  return objectPromise;
}

var resultDb =  scanDb();
console.log ("Result",resultDb);
```

**Expected output** : Scan results from DynamoDB.

**Actual Output** : Promise { "pending" }
​
: "pending"
​
: PromiseProto { … }

Answer (score 2):

`scanDb` is an async function, so it will necessarily return a promise. All async functions return promises. Either call .then on that promise, or use it in an async function and await its result.

```
scanDb()
  .then(resultDb => {
    console.log(resultDb);
  });
```

```
async function someFunction() {
  const resultDb = await scanDb();
  console.log(resultDb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas,  I get the results using your method. 
But my code does not wait for the results to come back and keeps on executing next line of code. I dont understand why my code wont wait till the scanDb result is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Await works on only inside async function, so it will hold the code after await, which is inside async. I was trying to get the value of scanDb() function outside of async.That the reason my code was not waiting.

Thanks a lot to Nicholas.